# mongodb installation on amazon ec2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to install mongodb on amazon ec2 as per [the official mongodb documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/). 
My amazon instance is ubuntu but the problem is the installation process hangs up at mongodb-org-server every time. Here are the logs

```
> sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell
  mongodb-org-tools
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 121 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/50.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 157 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-shell.
(Reading database ... 70167 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-shell_3.0.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-shell (3.0.6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-server_3.0.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-server (3.0.6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-mongos.
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-mongos_3.0.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (3.0.6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-tools.
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-tools_3.0.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-tools (3.0.6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org.
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org_3.0.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org (3.0.6) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-shell (3.0.6) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-server (3.0.6) ...
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you trying to run this on ?

Comment: I'm using version 14.04